# npm is broken and i can not run any npm command

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

My npm is broken and I could not run any npm command.

```
$ type npm
npm is hashed (/usr/local/bin/npm)

$ type node
node is hashed (/usr/local/bin/node)

$ type nodejs
nodejs is hashed (/usr/bin/nodejs)

$ uname -a 
Linux mj-lp-mint 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Versions:

```
$ node -v
v11.0.0

$ nodejs -v
v10.13.0
```

Following npm command gave this error:

```
$ sudo npm install npm -g

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:57
log.progressEnabled = log.gauge.isEnabled()
                                ^

TypeError: log.gauge.isEnabled is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:57:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:22:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:153:3)
```

Why **node** and **nodejs** has different versions and  **npm -v** gave same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're facing [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npmlog/issues/48). The short solution seems to be:

> Delete `node_modules/npm` and then run `yarn install` again.

There are other solutions in the issue comment thread.

Comment: in Ubuntu: /usr/lib/node_modules/*

Answer (score 5):

In windows i was getting the same error

log.progressEnabled = log.gauge.isEnabled()

npm version is 6.13.4, i installed the @angular/cli for MVC development with asp.net core with angular.

I changed the 57 line from log.js
C:\Users\<>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.9.5\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\log.js

from

log.progressEnabled = log.gauge.isEnabled() to

log.progressEnabled = log.gauge.isEnabled

and npm started to work.

Comment: Resolved this just now. Changed the file at `D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog` using **MEMO**, searched for 'isEnabled' \*ding\* change search direction to downwards, remove `()` from `log.gauge.isEnabled()`. Save, just run `npm -v` again, worked.

Answer (score 3):

For windows, delete node_modules from the following path - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. What does this answer add, that the other answers, from a year ago needed?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, download an installer from the official website, run it and at the end of the installation process, choose **"Automatically install the necessary tools. Note that this will also install Chocolately. The script will pop-up in a new window after the installation completes."**

I had the same issue and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For me on Windows 10, what worked was:
`I deleted node_modules directory under the installation folder`
but doing that alone did not work, `I also used the installer to repair the installation`
and after that all was good again, hope that helps someone else..

Answer (score -3):

I removed **/usr/local/lib/node_modules/** directory and everything works correctly:

`sudo rm -rfv /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

Hope it will help others ;-)

Comment: Warning: this will delete your global packages, and "npm linked" symlinks